# Reading stdin in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have some programming assignments which read input data from stdin like this:

```
text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

I am using Spyder as my development environment, and am not able to find a way to give the stdin. So, I added a -infile option to the code, and am reading from the file.

However, when submitting, I need to revert back to reading the stdin. How can I read stdin in the first place? I know how to do this from linux command line, but for now have to use windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The code you posted only works to read text when you run it in a system terminal (i.e. bash or cmd.exe).

It doesn't work in Spyder because its terminals are implemented in a different technology (PyQt vs. readline).

Comment: :-( I was hoping terminal like behavior.

Comment: Sorry, Spyder is a graphical application so we can't provide terminal behavior for this kind of things.

Comment: I've managed such thing by setting `Run Configuration` as `Execute in an external system terminal` in `Run` menu. You can press green button as usual and switch to the console.