# Python redirect standard input to file descriptor

Tags: python, stdin, file-descriptor

Let's say I have a file `data.txt`:

```
1
2
3 4 5
```

And I have a Python Program:

```
fd = open('data.txt')
sys.stdin = fd

a= int(input()) # expect to be 1
b= int(input()) # expect to be 2
c = [int(e) for e in input().strip().split(' ')] # expect to be [3, 4, 5]

sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__    # Reset the stdin to its default value
```

By running this script, I expect to have 3 variables `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = [3, 4, 5]`.

But when the program runs into `input()`, it just stucks there, instead of reading a line from file descriptor.

May I ask that how shall I correct this program?

Thanks,

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works for me.

Comment: Maybe you should give more details on your environment: OS and version, as well as exact Python version

Comment: Same as Vasilis. Are you running this code in an unusual environment that does weird things with builtins, like pycharm's PyDev console?

Comment: [Check here](https://repl.it/repls/ShimmeringDistantMass), it runs without issues. Maybe you forgot the newline at the end of your textfile?

Comment: Hi Everyone: Windows 10, Python 3.5.3 , IDE: Spyder 3.1.4

Comment: Hi Everyone, everything works fine for running @Arne 's code. But it just doesn't work when it comes to Spyder...

Comment: If possible, try to set up an exact example that we can run to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found out the issue here: it is because Spyder Python does not support redirecting input.

See [Reading stdin in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671039/reading-stdin-in-spyder)