# How to debug with the input() function call using Spyder?

Tags: python, debugging, console, user-input, spyder

I'm trying to debug a python script in Spyder.  I start Debug mode, the script prints to the screen some menu items and then stops at the input() function call waiting for a response from the user.  My breakpoint is beyond the input() function but I don't know how to get past this point.

`cmdStr = input()`

Is there some sort of Console window that I'm not seeing where a user can type in a menu option to continue running?  I have the IPython console that is giving me a ipdb> prompt but when I type the menu option here the script crashes with this error . . .

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So, I'm guessing this is the wrong console window to be typing my menu option.  Is there another standard Windows console window that is linked to the running python script?

Comment: Try converting the string to `bytes`, e.g. `'hello'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: It's close, but it's not seeing the string inside the quotes. So, it just returns to the input() function.  I also tried double quotes and got the same thing.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671039/reading-stdin-in-spyder